# My Android activity does not clear itself and causes problems I restart it

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, reset, restart

I have an activity containing very complicated operation with many Threads and objects.

When I click on the "back" button to leave the activity, and then I restart it : all my threads do not work correctly. But if I kill the app and restart the activity, it works !

I think I have some static vars to clear, but there is some others problems (for example some Threads not finished etc !?).

So my question is : how to **TOTALLY** reset an Activity without leaving the app ?

Comment: you should check the Android livecycle for activitys here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html there are some Methods like onDestroty() which can help you with this

Comment: You should stop all your threads on the onPause(), so you don't leave any pending operation when leaving the activity.

Comment: Yes but is there a method can provide this *System.exit(0);* but without leaving the app ?

Comment: i would use a threadpool to run your threads and call the method to terminate all before leaving the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a homemade *MultiMap<Double, Thread>* : the *Double* indicate the interrupt scheduling. This MultiMap is a *TreeMap<Double, LinkedList<WeakReference<Thread>>>*. Then I interrupt all threads with the right ordering. I must do this because some of my threads launch others threads.

Moreover, I set *null* all static vars in my package. But It's **ugly** because I must call public methods at the start of the Activity.

Thx for your comments.